# Export out wallet addresses and token map from a solidity contract

Tags: erc-721, mapping, export

How to export out wallet addresses and ERC721 token ownership map from a solidity contract?

I am looking to export this map outside of the contract at anytime as a snapshot then import it into a different contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that, unless you have all the keys or it's your contract and you implement a functionality like that.

Here a couple of approaches:

You can either create a logic in the contract to return/export all the data from a `mapping`. For that, the contract will need to hace an arrays of keys that it uses to save all the keys when a new element is added to the mapping, and removed when an element is removed from the mapping.

Then, you just need to create a function that loops through that array and for each key it goes getting the value in the mapping, saving them in a `memory` array of those values and returning them after de loop.

If it's not your contract or you don't want to implement a logic like that, then your other option is to have all the keys anyways, then call the getter function of the mapping in a loop with each of the keys.

If there's no public/external getter function for the mapping, then you need to get the values of each key directly from storage with something like:

```js
wev3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, storageIndexForEachKey);
```

to get the values directly from the storage of the contract.

Here you can learn how to access the storage directly, for arrays, mappings, etc: https://coinsbench.com/solidity-layout-and-access-of-storage-variables-simply-explained-1ce964d7c738